# Web service error: The XML element 'Profile' from namespace... references a method and a type

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a webservice proxy generated with svcutils, when using the webservice I get the error

**The XML element 'Profile' from namespace 'http://schemas.soa.tretretre.it/Architettura/ProfilingSchema/2012-09-18' references a method and a type.
Change the method's message name using WebMethodAttribute or change the type's root element using the XmlRootAttribute."**

In the generate code there are two occurences of "Profile":

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]

/*** HERE IT IS ****/

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="Profile", WrapperNamespace="http://schemas.soa.tretretre.it/Architettura/ProfilingSchema/2012-09-18", IsWrapped=true)]
    public partial class getProfileResponse
    {    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.soa.tretretre.it/Architettura/ProfilingSchema/2012-09-18", Order=0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ApplicationProfile")]
        public ApplicationProfile[] ApplicationProfile;

        public getProfileResponse()
        {
        }

        public getProfileResponse(ApplicationProfile[] ApplicationProfile)
        {
            this.ApplicationProfile = ApplicationProfile;
        }
    }

.......

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]

/*** HERE IT IS ****/
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="Profile", WrapperNamespace="http://schemas.soa.tretretre.it/Architettura/ProfilingSchema/2012-09-18", IsWrapped=true)]


    public partial class getMobileProfileResponse
    {  [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.soa.tretretre.it/Architettura/ProfilingSchema/2012-09-18", Order=0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ApplicationProfile")]
        public ApplicationProfile[] ApplicationProfile;

        public getMobileProfileResponse()
        {
        }

        public getMobileProfileResponse(ApplicationProfile[] ApplicationProfile)
        {
            this.ApplicationProfile = ApplicationProfile;
        }
    }
```

Changing the namespace of the first "Profile" occurence from: "http://schemas.soa.tretretre.it/Architettura/ProfilingSchema/2012-09-18"

to

"http://schemas.soa.tretretre.it/Architettura/ProfilingSchema/2012-09-18TEST"

Solves the problem.

I don't have access to the services and I don't know much about web services.
Can you please explain me what kind of situation server side might have generated the problem? I mean what kind of class / object definition.. 
I understand it is some kind of name conflict but I' d like a clear example or explanation...

Comment: It seems that service has invalid wsdl.

Comment: I'm not really sure because from my researches I found that is quite a common problem...

Comment: Having the same problem using a WSDL definition generated by a WebLogic Java web service. Looks like the .Net client doesn't like the WebLogic definitions, still looking for a solution.